# wordpress - удалить ненужные изображения

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, изображения

Приветствую! Есть сайт на wordpress с огромным количеством постов разных типов и огромным количеством изображений - примерно 300,000 штук. Предполагаю, что четверть из изображений - не используются, так как посты иногда удаляются. Как мне выявить изображения, что не используются в постах (разных типов), в мета-данных (широко используется на сайте плагин Advanced Custom Fields), и в итоге их удалить?

По-сути нужно циклом прогнать все изображения и как-то проверить, не упоминаются ли они в базе данных.

Всяческие плагины типа DNUI просто-напросто виснут при сканировании - не хватает оперативной памяти для процессов php. У кого какие идеи? Спасибо

Comment: Если попытаться привязать это к программированию, то вы наверняка знакомы с API WordPress? Что конкретно вас интересует, готовый плагин, запрос? Начните писать плагин и задавайте конкретные вопросы. Вот ссылка которая возможно поможет: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149156/how-do-i-delete-all-unused-images-from-my-uploads-directory

Comment: хорошо, я выбрал запросом все посты типа attachment из базы, как мне проверить, принадлежит ли изображение к какому-то произвольному полю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если только в метаполях, то запросом, вызвав $wpdb. Надо заджойнить ID атачментов изображений с meta_value, и отобрать те у которых будет NULL. Вот по этим ID потом идти циклом и удалять.